# Several Routers and DMZ, WAN, Local LAN

Tags: routing, dhcp, dmz

I previously had:

- A PS3 directly connected to the router given to me by my ISP (Router A). I had the console in a DMZ on this router at IP 192.168.1.33
- So I had enabled UPnP for this router and setup DHCP for this router from 192.168.1.50 to 192.168.1.100, but set the console with a fixed IP of 192.168.1.33 to avoid conflict with the IPs seved by DHCP server, this has been working fine.
- A PS4 with open ports from this router A and fixed IP at 192.168.1.34 (not important here)

Now my setup will be like this:

- I will take and connect the PS3 to a second router, Router B (located in a a different floor of the house), which is connected to Router A via Ethernet cable
- Note: I am making this problem simpler here, there is indeed a Router C connected to Router B and then the PS3 connected to Router C.
- I want full internet access for Router B so I will later be able to open/create a DMZ or opening ports in Router B so the PS3 will not suffer NAT issues.
- Router A (from my ISP) will have now DMZ open pointing to Router B's WAN IP 192.168.1.40 (the IP where it receives data from router A).
- Router B will have DHCP enabled as Router A, from 192.168.2.50 to 192.168.2.100, and PS3 will be now at 192.168.2.33
- As I want to create this DMZ in Router A pointing to Router B's WAN IP (let's say 192.168.1.40) I have to set Router B's WAN IP as 192.168.1.40, but what would be the other data to set in Router B's WAN page (the data coming from Router A)

> In Router A's WAN page I have this info (modified for privacy, but
>   let's suppose it is real)
>
> - WAN Address    65.125.71.62
> - Subnet Mask    255.255.214.0
> - Gateway Address    65.126.54.1
> - DNS Server 1   62.51.35.248
> - DNS Server 2   62.51.26.113
>
> Router A Private LAN page:
>
> - IP Private LAN      192.168.1.1
> - Subnet mask       255.255.255.0

What I know is that Router B will have the LAN IP address at 192.168.2.1 and will serve DHCP as I said from 192.168.2.50 to 192.168.2.100

So please, help me guessing the info I have insert in Router B's WAN page - setting static IP address:

- IP Address   192.168.1.40 (I guess, as I do with the PS3 and PS4)
- Subnet mask  255.255.255.0 (I guess it is correct)
- Gateway Address 65.126.54.1 (I guess? this is my biggest doubt)
- DNS Server 1 62.51.35.248  (I guess)
- DNS Server 2 62.51.26.113 (I guess)

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: Why don't you simply disable dhcp on router B, hard-code a local IP outside the range of dhcp, and ensure it is connected using one of the LAN ports (not WAN)? Allow router A to handle all dhcp requests. This keeps everything on the same subnet and basically turns your router B into a hub/switch. You can set up the DMZ (using the *playstation* IP if you need it) on router A using the playstation IP.

Comment: Can I do That if every router (A, B and C) are also wifi routers? Your solution is quite clever but I need that DHCP con wifi for the tablets and phones in the house. Can I do something to avoid that?

Comment: Set a = ch1; b=ch5, c=ch11. Give them separate names. You will connect to whichever you pick, and router A will be the dhcp server. Or, just turn off the wifi on 2 of them. Just ensure that the two extra routers IPs are manually set to something other than the LAN IP of router A (typically routers are xx.xx.xx.1) and they have dhcp disabled. might want to disable any parental controls etc on B and C also. Beware that DMZ basically puts that one computer on the other side of the firewall though, so avoid using dmz if at all possible

Comment: Switches are the preferred way of doing this by the way. I use this method sometimes when I need a wifi access point in a far corner of the house or when I have an extra router but no cash for a switch.

Comment: Yes, assuming you're not doing anything that needs you to treat each area of your house separately, switches are the answer for this. Depending on the model of router B / C, you might be able to just use the LAN side of the routers to use them as slightly over-featured switches (by plugging Router A LAN -> Router B LAN and turning off DHCP on B, etc). Edit: Obviously then you wouldn't need to DMZ the second switch/router.